# how to build a dynamic menu using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net

I try to create a dynamic menu using jquery:

```
  function createMenu(array) {
            var main = $("#mainUl");
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {          
                main.append("<li>");
                $('li').append("<a href='#" + myArray[i].id + "'><span>" + myArray[i].id + "</span></a>");
                main.append("</li>");
            }    
        }
```

The menu is created, but in each li i get more than one span, there is an "inside" loop (I think...)
createing more spans than needed... how can i solve/control it so each li gets
 one span according to the for - loop index ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it simply as below

```
  function createMenu(array) {
                var main = $("#mainUl");
                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {          
                    main.append($("<li>").append("<a href='#" + myArray[i].id + "'><span>" + myArray[i].id + "</span></a>"));
                }    
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing that behaviour because you are appending that `anchor` with `span` in selecting all the `li` elements.

Try,

```
function createMenu(array) {
    var main = $("#mainUl");
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {          
      var xLi =("<li>").appendTo(main);
      xLi.append("<a href='#" + myArray[i].id + "'><span>" + myArray[i].id + "</span></a>");
      main.append(xLi);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$('li') this selector will get every li on the html so every time you iterate to create a new li element you gonna add a new span to all of them.

Try like this:

```
function createMenu(array) {
        var main = $("#mainUl");
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
            var menuLine = $('<li>');
            menuLine.html("<a href='#" + myArray[i].id + "'><span>" + myArray[i].id + " </span></a>" );                                
            main.append(menuLine);
        }    
    }
```

Comment: can you please remove that quote from the variable `menuline` ?